# How can I plot an iteration coordinate(x,y) data with only label in GNUplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the set of data like this

> 0 268 195 
>   1 353 199 
>   2 318 209 
>   3 268 232 
>   4 370 238 
>   5 326 253 
>   6 246 265 
>   7 372 284 
>   8 313 290 
>   9 258 297 
>   0 268 196 
>   1 353 199 
>   2 318 209 
>   3 268 233 
>   4 370 238 
>   5 325 253 
>   6 246 265 
>   7 372 284 
>   8 313 290 
>   9 258 297

I would like to use first column for label and second and third for (x,y) plot, however, I would like to plot only one time label without iteration. How should I do?

Thank you for help.

Comment: What do you mean "one time label without iteration"?

Comment: For example, fixed label as the first time label 0 for (268,195) ... label 9 for (258,297). For the second iteration, only (268,196), (353,199), .... will plot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like:

```
plot 'datafile' u 2:3:1 with labels
```

... I'm not really sure what you mean by "I would like to plot only one time label without iteration" ...

It looks to me like you want to only take 1 unique label.  E.g. only one label that is `0`, and only 1 label that is `1` etc.  For simplicity, I'll take the first with a small python script:

```
#test.py
import sys

seen = set()
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        num,rest = line.split(None,1)
        if num not in seen:
            seen.add(num)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Now we can plot our file in gnuplot:

```
plot '< python test.py yourdatafile' u 2:3:1 w labels
```

Here's a version of `test.py` which will average the positions of all the labels with the same "value".

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        num,x,y = map(int,line.split())
        d[num].append((x,y))

#now average
for k,v in d.items():
    x,y = zip(*v)
    avg_x = float(sum(x))/len(x)
    avg_y = float(sum(y))/len(y)
    print k,avg_x,avg_y
```

Comment: Yes, @mgilson but if i do something like that label plot iteration for any row of data. Could you suggest?

Comment: @MojiizAlamode -- I'm sorry, but I still am having a hard time following.  Do you mean that you want to end up with 10 labels?  (0-9) corresponding to the first 10 lines of the datafile (or lines 11-20)?

Comment: Am sorry for my English, I want to end up with 10 labels (0-9) correspondence to whole data.

Comment: You want 10 labels, but you have 20 points in the dataset.  How do you pick which 10 labels you want, and which 10 you don't?

Comment: How can I use the first column as index, which we not pick the same number of the first column. -- @mgilson am sorry I have not good skill for English, it seem like impossible to do this task.

Comment: Sorry but I try with your code, but it not work. I need to create script.py first and run to GNUplot right?, but when I try to run GNUplot error "warning: Skipping unreadable file "< python test.py data.dat" No data in plot" is occurs.

Comment: @MojiizAlamode -- It looks like you 1) don't have a new enough python installed or 2) don't have gnuplot built with support for pipes.  In the second case, you can create an intermediate file:  `python test.py > intermediate.dat` and then you can `plot 'intermediate.dat' u 3:2:1 w labels`.  What operating system are you using? -- I don't know anything about windows systems

Comment: Unfortunately, I using windows systems.